# How to map any arbitrary two points from image to mapview? In iOS overlay mapkit context

Tags: ios, mapkit, overlay

I can choose points from mapview and can overlay an image there so that image's top left and bottom right are mapped to corresponding mapview's points.

But how can I map any arbitrary two points (not those corner points) from image to mapview's two chosen points? Like the calibrate feature of this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mapcha/id956671318?mt=8

Any hints either SDK specific or math involved to guide towards the solutions are appreciated.

**Edited:**
I didn't realize that my explanation were not making sense to you, pardon.
I thought my requirement would easily make sense by providing [the reference app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mapcha/id956671318?mt=8) and reference feature (Calibrate).

OK, a bit more explanation here. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial) to achieve result like [this image](http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/MapOverlay.png). Now, all I want to do is to make my app users be able to attach their own images to the map at their desired places like that calibrate feature of the reference app.

**Note:**
You don't have to install the reference app to understand the calibrate feature as it can be understood by just viewing the images with title Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4 & Finish.

Here are those points' text in case reference would be no more available.

- Step 1: Take a picture of your map or use a photo from your photo library. Ensure North is up.
- Step 2: Choose a point on the paper map and locate it on the standard map.
- Step 3: Repeat for another point. Points that are farther apart give better results.
- Step 4: Preview the map and check alignment. Adjust the transparency if required.
- Finish: Now you can see your current location on the paper map.

**Edited:**

I'm not getting the desired result as shown in the image but seem close.

[image]

And here is a snap of code I'm using.

```
 -(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {

    CGImageRef imageReference = self.overlayImage.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    double imgWidthScaleFactor = 1.0;
    if (_imgWidth > 0) {
        imgWidthScaleFactor = theRect.size.width / _imgWidth;
    }

    double imgHeightScaleFactor = 1.0;
    if (_imgHeight > 0) {
        imgHeightScaleFactor = theRect.size.height / _imgHeight;
    }

    CGPoint contextCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(theRect), CGRectGetMidY(theRect));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, contextCenter.x, contextCenter.y);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, _radian);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -contextCenter.x, -contextCenter.y);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, imgWidthScaleFactor*_pivotX, imgHeightScaleFactor*_pivotY);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);

}
```

Comment: Would love to help, but not sure if I understand what you are trying to do - would you mind elaborating a little more? for example by attaching an image explaining what you are visually trying to do?

Comment: @zeeawan Can you add some of your code so we can understand in detail what you are developing.

Comment: I've edited my question. Let me know if that make sense now.

Comment: @zeeawan provided a detailed explanation below)

Comment: @zeeawan - are you getting these?

Comment: @trdavidson, yes, I'm getting these but I've been off the desk for a couple of days. Thanks for you explanation. Your explanation seems missing a) scale factor along x direction and y direction as image may not be uniformly scaled in cases b) angle of rotation like you've shown image's points with line like / so what if chosen map points make line like \ c) how to know the corner points using those chosen points (after or before rotation).

Comment: @zeeawan - I think you don't fully understand how the explanation below works:a) think about putting an image on a table, the moment you put  a needle through the middle you can freely rotate it around. However, the moment you put 2 needles on different places through it it's pinned down. Same here, if you only had one matching point of the map and the image to pin down, you wouldn't be able to scale it, when you have two however it becomes a uniform scale. b) Making a line like so \ or like so / doesn't matter given two points. c) Given you know the size of your image and scale this follows.

Comment: @trdavidson, I'm going to attach an image to my question to further clarify the requirement.

Comment: @zeeawan Did you manage to make this work? I am fighting with exactly same kind of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, let me start by explaining the intuition behind what this example app does:

image to stick on map:

```
/*    _____
     |     |
     |     |           __
     |_____|          |__|

  (image to stick)    (map)
*/
```

As you can see, i have made it such that the image shape and size, are different from the map. Now, the reason you have to pick two points on the map and two on the image is to provide a scale for your image.

```
/*    _____
     |   * |
     |*    |           
     |_____|          

   (image to stick, with chosen points as *)    
*/
```

I. calculate the distance between the two chosen points on the Image, and the two chosen points on the map, lets call them `d_image` and `d_map`.

Now you get the scaling of your image by simply doing:

```
float scale  = (d_map/d_image);
```

II. Using the scale you will be able to find the upper right corner of the image on the map, and the bottom left corner of the image on the map. You can use these points and convert them to coordinates using the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D image_corner_coordinate = [*yourMap* convertPoint:*image_corner* toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
```

And voila, you have your SouthWest and NorthEast coordinates to pin your overlay to!

***EDIT****

OP added additional information to the question with the explicit request to be able to handle images that are at a different angle than the chosen points on the map. Although I believe that the answer above, steps I and II should be enough to figure out how to achieve the desired effect, here we go for completeness sake:

step I (.5)

Using the scaling factor calculated in Step I. we first scale down the image to the appropriate size. Then, give than we know the two given points on the map and the two given points on the image, we calculate the rotation factor.

Given that the image is now the right scale, the way to think about this is the following: you pin down on of the two points on it's matching map point, and start to rotate the image until the other point matches up. When you find the rotation factor, continue to step II to get your final answer.